# EasyScreenCast doesn't see webcam fedora 29

Tags: fedora, gnome

I installed EasyScreenCast gnome extension and everything works fine, but it doesn't see my laptop webcam. Any ideas? Thanks everyone!

[EasyScreenCast settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeNVa.png)
[fedora navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNoiB.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you install it by Gnome shell extension or latest git repo release you must uncomment the lines with comment **"/* TODO: fix gstreamer init"** on extension.js file, present on the folder of extension.

you must free the lines 63, 134, 538, 553 after that reload the gnome shell process and enjoy...if the bug was fixed otherwise open an issue on github with the logs.